# Determine number of Kubernetes CPUs utilised over time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, performance-monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine

I have spent a bit of time in Kubernetes monitoring on GCP (https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/observing) and cannot find where to see how many CPUs were used by a particular service over the last 30 days. I only get overall cpu utilisation. I looked at container uptime in aggregate (count) to try and determine that way how many copies of an image were running at the same time, but to no avail. What's the best metric to use to determine what autoscaling happened in terms of CPUs and images?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to deploy grafana and prometheus from Marketplace? I think it could give you a good insight about what you want.

Comment: @KoopaKiller will check them out. Thanks

Comment: Please share your findings... it solved your issue?